# C# string parsing question

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to split a string:

```
 string f = r.ReadToEnd();
 string[] seperators = new string[] {"[==========]"};
 string[] result;
result = f.Split(seperators, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

There's this ========== thing that separates entries.  For the life of me, I can't get this to work.  I've got a ruby version working...BUT using the string splitter classes I thought I knew for .NET doesn't seem to be working so well.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What output *do* you get? It's possible the code is doing what you're asking it to do, but is not doing what you want it to do.

Comment: Examples of the input and output would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that the separator is `==========` but you're using `[==========]`. Try this:

```
string f = r.ReadToEnd();
string[] seperators = new string[] {"=========="};
string[] result;
result = f.Split(seperators, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: I saw that and thought "no, it couldn't be..."

Comment: Yeah... me too. That would be *too* easy.

Comment: what can I say? :-) The code looks perfect, that's the only weird thing

Comment: I got rid of the brackets and it seemed to work.  I should have thought of that...the confusing thing is that you are supposed to pass it an array.  It should have been clear, though, because the brackets were in the literals.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code with the following modification:

```
string f = "string1[==========]string2[==========]string3";
string[] seperators = new string[] { "[==========]" };
string[] result;
result = f.Split(seperators, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (string x in result) Console.WriteLine(x);
```

The function writes out the strings as expected. I'd look at the contents of your file more closely - perhaps there is something in the encoding, or some other character that is missing when you devise a separator to work in C#/Windows.